# Cannot create an Application with OJET-CLI

Tags: npm, command-line-interface, oracle-jet

I am a beginner on Oracle JET. I tried to install a sample ojet application which is mentioned in the documentation. I have set both http and https proxy. I have node and npm installed on my system. I am able to download other packages using npm like npm-check etc. but when I try

```
ojet create HelloJET --web --template=navdrawer
```

it goes through some time and often stuck at this point
[image: npm console output]

Comment: its not a proxy issue if it is able to reach that point.. how long does it stay stuck? are your node and npm up to date?

Comment: It was stuck there for about 10 hours and then i have cancelled it

Comment: You are on select mode in CMD... press esc....

Answer (score 1):

In CMD when you mark something up for selection the header of the window changes to

```
Select <process>
```

You need to press esc to exit from select mode.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the problem is that white spot in the middle of screen,

[image]

you needed to press ESC to let the rest the script to run